# Event Emitter not working in child component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my angular app, If I route through url event emitter emitted events not triggering in parent component.

Ex:

If I type complete url in browser. http://localhost:4200/child

My Child component is loading. But close event emitter emitted events not trigged in parent component.Below is my code.

File: `app.routing.module.ts`

```
  const routes: Routes = [
   
    {path : 'child', component : ChildComponent},
    
  ];
```

File: `app.component.html`

```
    <div>
    <app-bibdpayment *ngIf="show == true" (close)="cancel()"></app-bibdpayment>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

File: `app.component.ts`

```
    cancel() {
        this.show = false;
    }
```

File: `childcomponent.html`

```
   <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

File: `childcomponent.ts`

```
    @Output() close = new EventEmitter<void>();  
    cancel() {
       this.close.emit();
    }
```

Why event emitter is not working. When we call the child component url directly.

How to resolve this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: `(close)="cancel($event)` and `this.close.emit(1)` try updating with this and check in the console whether you're receiving the event or not?

Answer (score 1):

You assign true for show in the template and for this reason the value of show contain same all the time.so you have to manage the value of show from component.ts file. For your better understanding I am giving the code details bellow:

> **ChildComponent.ts**

```
@Output() close = new EventEmitter<any>();

cancel() 
{
  this.close.emit();
}
```

> **ParantComponent.html**

******you do not need to assign value for **show** variable in *ngIf condition.  just put the variable on *ngIf and follow my steps.******

```
<app-bibdpayment *ngIf="show" (close)= "close()"></app-bibdpayment>
```

> **ParantComponent.ts**

**define a global variable like in the following:**

```
show = true;
```

**then declare your function & follow my steps in the ParantComponent.ts file:**

```
close()
{
  this.show = false;
}
```

Hope it will work. Thank you! :(